# Trying to convert Query result into JSON format and send it back to my phone (Android)

Tags: php, json

I am trying to query mySql Database on my server using PHP following is my code:

```
   <?php

    require 'phtry.php';

    $message = 1 ; //$_POST["message"]; 

    $query = "SELECT `surname`,`firstname` FROM `users`";


    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE id = $message";

   if ($query_run = mysql_query($query1)){
      //echo 'Success.';
      while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){

      $surname = $query_row['surname'];
      $firstname = $query_row['firstname'];


}


$out [] = $query_row;
print(json_encode($out));

}else{
    echo 'No Success';
}
```

However the statement print(json_encode($out)); gives me an output of [false]. Can anyone direct me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $out inside while loop

```
if ($query_run = mysql_query($query1)){
 //echo 'Success.';
 while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){

 $surname = $query_row['surname'];
 $firstname = $query_row['firstname'];
 $out[] = $query_row;

}
print(json_encode($out));
}else{
 echo 'No Success';
}
```